# No associated key pair, add key pair to EC2 with no key pair

Tags: amazon-ec2, public-key, private-key, key

How do you add an existing key to a live EC2 instance that has no key pair?

I have tried using Session Manager to `vi /.ssh/authorized_keys` and add in the public key of the pair, but I get this error:

```
"~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
"~/.ssh/authorized_keys" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Is this something that has to be done using the console?

```
No associated key pair
This instance is not associated with a key pair. Without a key pair, you can't connect to the instance through SSH.
You can connect using EC2 Instance Connect with just a valid username. You can connect using Session Manager if you have been granted the necessary permissions.
```

Comment: Does it have any ssh key installed? If you need to add additional SSH public key to destination .ssh/authorized_keys, I would just run  ```ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/publicsshkey.pub $server ip```

There is also a way to add it through the AWS console:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me associate the key pair using the AWS console with EC2 instance. I have followed the directions for adding the authorized_keys using ssh using Session Manager (since it has no key pair) - but that does not let me shell in, and the console still indicates no key pair

Comment: Here is what I mean:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-key-pair.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

Since you’ve got Systems Manager configured you’re half-way there. The only thing standing between you and success is the fact that Systems Manager Session opens the session as `ssm-user` and you’ll need to do `sudo -u ec2-user -i` first and once you're logged in as `ec2-user` do the subsequent steps.

Then you may have to create the `~ec2-user/.ssh` directory if it doesn’t exist and chmod it to 700.

And finally you can add the public key to `~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and chmod that file to 600.

That should do the trick :)

Comment: That works temporarily - after the session or on restart/reboot, it seems it is wiped out maybe by some sort of AWS global daemon.

Comment: If the key is in `~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` it will stay there. But it sounds like you put it to `~ssm-user/.ssh/…` - that home directory is wiped as soon as you log out from the SSM session.

Comment: ah, your directions did not indicate ~ec2-user/ being base directory...

Comment: Yeah I said that you have to do `sudo -u ec2-user -i` first and once you're logged in as `ec2-user` do the subsequent steps. Sorry, should have been more explicit. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of how valid an approach this is ...

If you use a userdata script to pull a public key from somewhere (say parameter store) and then add a user and setup that user's `.ssh` directory, then you can effectively login via SSH without a keypair being directly attached to the EC2 (as such) ... I think.

We have a bastion server that allows us to create tunnels to specific endpoints with AWS, and with an option to allow PTY, so you can actually SSH onto the bastion. Without that option, you can only SSH tunnel through the bastion to a controlled set of services.

The function in the userdata script (we're using a shell script rather than YAML).

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

build_user ()
{
    # Extract parameters
    # ==================

    # SSH Username / Parameter Store key, TTY Allowed, Permission group
    local username="$1"
    local tty=$2
    local permGroup="PERM_GROUP_$3"


    # Define working variables
    # ========================

    # Get the collection of tunnels from the permission group
    local tunnels="$${!permGroup}"

    # SSH Directory, authorised_keys filename, and default SSH restrictions
    local sshDirectory="/home/$username/.ssh"
    local sshAuthorizedKeyFile="$sshDirectory/authorized_keys"
    local sshRestrictions="restrict,port-forwarding"

    # Create account
    echo "Create account for $username"
    useradd "$username" || echo "The account $username already exists."
    if [ ! -d "$sshDirectory" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$sshDirectory"
        chmod 700 "$sshDirectory"
    fi


    # Define the SSH restrictions
    # ===========================

    # Allow TTY if allowed
    if [ "$tty" == "true" ]; then
        local sshRestrictions="$sshRestrictions,pty"
    fi

    # Add allowed tunnels based upon permission group
    for tunnel in $${tunnels[@]}; do
        sshRestrictions="$sshRestrictions,permitopen=\"$tunnel\""
    done


    # Build and set the correct permissions on the authorized_keys file
    # =================================================================
    echo "# $username" > "$sshAuthorizedKeyFile"
    SSH_KEYS=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name /BASTION/SSH_PUBLIC_KEYS/$username --region $AWS_REGION --with-decryption --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text)
    echo "$SSH_KEYS" | while IFS= read -r ssh_key; do
        echo "$sshRestrictions $ssh_key" >> "$sshAuthorizedKeyFile"
    done
    chmod 600 "$sshAuthorizedKeyFile"
    chown -R "$username":"$username" "$sshDirectory"
}
```

In addition to the function we have some generated calls/setup (we're using Terraform for this).

```
# Define the permission groups
# ============================
%{ for perm_group,perms in bastion_perm_groups ~}
PERM_GROUP_${upper(perm_group)}="%{ for perm in perms }${perm} %{ endfor }"
%{ endfor ~}

# Get the AWS Region we are deployed in
# =====================================
AWS_REGION=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region)

# Create users and their authorized_keys
# ======================================
%{ for name, user in bastion_users ~}
build_user ${name} ${user.tty} ${upper(user.perm_group)}
%{ endfor ~}
```

So we have a list of permission groups (effectively READ_ONLY and READ_WRITE). Each of those groups lists a load of RDS and Redis endpoints.

The users is a list of names, with a `true`/`false` if they have PTY access and then the group name they need to have.

The net result is a list of directories in the `/home` directory, one per user, a `.ssh/authorized_keys` in each user directory controlling what they are allowed to do via SSH.

A lot of this was given to us. Is it secure? Well. I think if you know what you're doing, you can always get around all sorts of things. But the list of users is carefully controlled and there are other security elements not detailed here.

By having this as the userdata script for the launching of the EC2 (we're using a launch configuration via an autoscaling group at the moment and plan to move to launch templates), if it is rebooted or replaced, then the script is run and so you don't lose SSH tunneling capability. IP address probably will change, so an EIP is useful here.

If you want to update things without redeploying the bastion, you can by running:

```
curl http://instance-data/latest/user-data | sudo sh
```

So a completely different way of handling the no key pair and a way to allow multiple people to have controlled logins.

If any of this is slightly useful to the question, then great! If not, then just ignore me.